# Break a text into multiple lines in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I save more strings inside an array. What I want to do is to show them when hover over an icon each of them on separate lines.
What I tried so far:

```
addMessages = () => {
   const text = [];

   //add strings in the array

   return text.join("<hr/>");

}

render() {
   const showWhenHover = this.addMessages();

   return (
            <ActionBar popover={<div> {showWhenHover}</div>}
               <div>
                   <Icon type="myIcon"/>
               </div>
           </ActionBar>
          );
      }
}
```

When I hover over the icon it shows the messages but not each of them on a separate line but all in one line like this:

```
text1</hr>text2</hr>text3
```

Isn't `<hr/>` what must be used in this case? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `<br>`

Comment: I tried also with that but what I think is that it doesn't recognise the tag, it takes it like plain text

Comment: showWhenHover all returns a text node. If you will have it render as markup you want to return a React.Component instance.

Comment: `return (<div>{text.map((txt, i) => <div key={i}>{txt}<br></div> )}</div>);` in `addMessages`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text.join` will render a single string, including `<hr />` in this case. In order to render JSX instead, try:

```
addMessages = () => {
  const text = [];

  // add strings in the array

  return text.map((item, index) => (
    <span key={index}>
      {item}
      {index && <hr />}
    </span>
  ));
}
```

Only downside here is the extra span, but I would prefer this over using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: It makes it better but not as it must to be. I mean, if there are 2 strings in the array `s1` and `s2` it shows s1s2 <hr/> s1s2. It there are 3 strings, it shows s1s2s3<hr/>s1s2s3<hr/s1s2s3>. I hope my explanation is clear

Comment: solved it. it must be used `text[index]` instead of `text` inside the span.

Comment: Yeah sorry it was my mistake, I renamed the parameter to `item` to make it clearer, so you don't need to use text[index]. 

Answer (score 4):

Your function addMessage generates strings and not a html markup.

One solution is to use template literals allow [multiline strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings). The other thing is that make sure that the text are contained within an element that has defined dimensions, or dimensions big enough that the text can go to the next line.

```js
const genText = () => `
  Text with lots of
  spaces within 
  it blah blah blah
  blah
`

const Comp = () => <div style={{width: 100, height: 200}}>{genText()}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<Comp />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `return text.map(e => <div>{e}</div>);` to get each string in its own line.

```js
function addMessages() {
   const text = [];
   
   text.push("1st line");
   text.push("2nd line");
   text.push("Third line");
   text.push("And a final one");

   return text.map(e => <div>{e}</div>);
}


const App = () => <div>{addMessages()}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```